How to prove the following inequality about normalized complex vectors?
Let $|a\rangle , |b\rangle $ be normalized complex vectors in the same space, how to prove that
$\underset{\left\| |\psi \rangle \right\| =1}{\max}\left| \langle a|\psi \rangle \langle \psi |b\rangle \right|^2=\left( \frac{1+\left| \langle a|b\rangle \right|}{2} \right) ^2$
It is easy to prove this for real vectors by using angle.I want to know that is it real for complex vectors?

By orthogonally projecting $\psi$ on $\text{Span}(a,b)$ we get a $\phi$ such that $||\phi||\leq 1$ and $\langle a|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|b\rangle=\langle a|\phi\rangle \langle\phi|b\rangle$, so by rescaling it's sufficient to prove the inequality for $\psi\in\text{Span}(a,b)$ such that $||\psi||=1$. Given an orthonormal base $\{\psi,\phi\}$ of $\text{Span}(a,b)$ and writing $a=x\psi+y\phi$ and $b=z\psi+w\phi$ for some $x,y,z,w$ such that $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2=1$, we can rewrite the inequality as
$$2|xz|\leq 1+|xz+yw|.$$
Now using the triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $$2|xz|\leq |xz-yw|+|xz+yw|\leq 1+|xz+yw|,$$ so we are done.
I'm sure there's a less "coordinates dependent" solution, but I couldn't find it.

I get your prove, thanks. There's just one small problem, notions $\phi$ and $\psi$ are repeated.
